# How to mod_write query param to path for arbitrarily long path?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a simple API with apache and I want to map `/really/long/path/api/captions.php?caption_id=blah` to `/really/long/path/api/captions/blah`. It's important to NOT have to specify a full path in the rewrite rule because I want this to work no matter where I deploy this code to. However, I can't find/figure out a working example of `.htaccess` rewrite rules that enable me to match based upon only the final part of the extension.

So, assuming that I have, say, `captions.php` in a dir called `api`, what `.htaccess` file do I need to include in `api` to accomplish this transform without having `/really/long/path/` anywhere therein?

(I also want to be able to map `/really/long/path/api/captions.php` to `/really/long/path/api/captions/` and `/really/long/path/api/captions`.)

I've tried all sorts of wildcard-like syntax; here's one of those non-working attempts:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?captions/(.*?)/?$ /captions.php?caption_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /captions\.php\?caption_id=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?captions\.php$ /captions/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there in the end. This is all that was needed:

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^captions/?$ captions.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^captions/(.*)/?$ captions.php?caption_id=$1 [NC,L]
```